# Bootstrap custom checkbox or radio not-clickable

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Why this markup doesn't work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="b4qw8"> 8. Возможность бронирования по времени и месту.
    </label>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="Да" name="b4qw8" class="custom-control-input" value="Да">
        <span class="custom-control-label" for="Да">Да
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="Нет" name="b4qw8" class="custom-control-input" value="Нет">
        <span class="custom-control-label" for="Нет">Нет
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="b3qw4"> 4. Вид общественного питания:
    </label>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Ресторан" value="Ресторан"> Ресторан
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Ресторан">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Кофе" value="Кофе"> Кофе
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Кофе">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Столовая" value="Столовая"> Столовая
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Столовая">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Бар" value="Бар"> Бар
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Бар">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Кофе-бар" value="Кофе-бар"> Кофе-бар
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Кофе-бар">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Клуб" value="Клуб"> Клуб
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Клуб">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Другое" value="Другое"> Другое
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="Другое">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors">
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/polopolaw/pen/MWabqzr

I have same problem with checboxes, theirs behavior so strange. 1,3,4 checbox not working in forth question https://regional.tours/#step-3. But murkup generated via Flask, therefore checkboxes haven't differecess.

Comment: the question is to general. Please try to describe the problem better (what exactly doesn't work in your markup) and simplify your code example as much as possible (remove all code that is not related to the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `span` to `label` Like below.

> `<label class="custom-control-label" for="Да">Да</label>`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="b4qw8"> 8. Возможность бронирования по времени и месту.
  </label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Да" name="b4qw8" class="custom-control-input" value="Да">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Да">Да</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Нет" name="b4qw8" class="custom-control-input" value="Нет">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Нет">Нет</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="b3qw4"> 4. Вид общественного питания:
  </label>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Ресторан" value="Ресторан"> Ресторан
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Ресторан"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Кофе" value="Кофе"> Кофе
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Кофе"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Столовая" value="Столовая"> Столовая
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Столовая"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Бар" value="Бар"> Бар
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Бар"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Кофе-бар" value="Кофе-бар"> Кофе-бар
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Кофе-бар"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Клуб" value="Клуб"> Клуб
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Клуб"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="b3qw4" id="Другое" value="Другое"> Другое
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Другое"></label>
  </div>

  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!